# RxJS Asynchronous Request Update

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs

So, I'm currently learning to think Reactively thanks to RxJS.  Now, I'm currently reading an RxJS book (Reactive Programming with RxJS) and I've read about AsyncSubject and how it only caches the last value received.  What I'd like to know is, what happens if I want to update the server and have this observable update?  Since onComplete has been called, do I need to create a brand new observer?  Is there another pattern I should follow?

My overall requirement is that I'd like to have a means to cleanly pass data to and from the server and keep my observable (model) fresh at all times.

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: Why not use Observable with Websockets?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about the behaviour that you seek. For instance, specify input vs. expected output, or draw a marble diagram. Also it would be nice if you explain why/who onComplete is called/calls

Comment: I simply needed to be able to query the server when needed, rather than create a new observer each time.  I wasn't quite sure how to stop an observer from completing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, you cannot change the value of an AsyncSubject after onCompleted has been called. The typical way of dealing with a simple "call the server as required, cache the value between calls" scenario is to use flatMapLatest to map your trigger observable to an AsyncSubject representing your server call. For example, if you wanted to refresh some data every 30 seconds, you might do something like this:

```
const subscription = Rx.Observable
   .interval(30000)
   .flatMapLatest(() => serverCall())
   .subscribe(x => doStuffWithResult(x));
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  In my instance, I will be using a subject trigger, rather than an interval, to ensure that the server is queried only when needed and no more.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would consider using Websockets, since you want `your observable (model) fresh at all times`

Something like

```
var source = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
   websocket.onmessage = function( msg ) {
      observer.onNext( msg );
   }

   websocket.onerror = function( error ) {
      observer.onError( error );
   }

   websocket.onclose = function ( msg ) {
      observer.onComplete( msg );
   }
});
```

Otherwise you can use an interval

```
const subscription = Rx.Observable
   .interval(1000)
   .flatMapLatest(() => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch( ... ).then( response => response.json() ).retry(5))
   .subscribe( response => response );
```

You can always use the `retry` operator to not give up immediately if there is an error.

Comment: Thanks, your second example is better.  I need to avoid websockets at present as the REST interface is already available.